# to invoke interface method 'retrofit2.Call on a null object reference

Tags: retrofit2

how can i solve null object while sending post request
error says
to invoke interface method 'retrofit2.Call com.itgrepnet.foodbundle.remote.UserService.addUser(com.itgrepnet.foodbundle.model.User)' on a null object reference

in AddUserActivity

```
btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            addNewUser();
        }

        private void addNewUser() {
            User u = new User();
            u.setFirstname(first_name.getText().toString());
            u.setLastname(last_name.getText().toString());
            u.setEmail(email.getText().toString());
            u.setPassword(password.getText().toString());

            Call<User> call = userService.addUser(u);

            call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Created Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.e("Error: ", t.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

UserService.java

```
@POST("user/")
    Call<User> addUser(@Body User user);
```

RetrofitClient.java

```
public class RetrofitClient {

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient(String url) {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(url)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Comment: The error says that `userService` is null. Do you ever call `userService = RetrofitClient.getClient("some URL").create(UserService.class)`?

Comment: thanks @Fred now solved